# How to expose PP2P without router port-forwarding (with ngrok?)

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding

My main target is to create a PP2P VPN server and expose it, without doing port forwarding on router.

I've used this [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/) to create an usual PP2P VPN server on windows and now I can connect locally to the server.
The problem is that I don't have access to the router so I can't expose it by modifying router's settings.

So, how I can expose my PP2P VPN server to the internet?

**What I've tried:**
Exposed local port 1723 with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

```
ngrok tcp 1723
```

And tried to connect to the url (generated by ngrok) using [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/134046/how-to-connect-to-a-vpn-in-windows/). 
But it didn't work.
Also I'm wondering whether exposing the [port 43](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB5671) would help or not (if yes, then I should buy ngrok).

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

That won't be enough, because you're only able to expose the *control* connection – you cannot do anything for the GRE tunnel used for data transfer.

There is no such thing as "the GRE port", because GRE itself **is not TCP-based nor UDP-based;** it runs directly on top of IP (alongside these two protocols). GRE is only identified by IP-level protocol number '47', similar to how TCP itself has number '6' and UDP is '17'.

(Actually even if you *had* access to your router, there's very high chance it wouldn't let you configure a port-forwarding for GRE anyway. It's unfortunate but many consumer-grade routers deliberately limit themselves to just TCP and UDP.)

Your goal cannot be achieved with PPTP. Consider using third-party VPN software (most of which is UDP-based and sometimes has TCP support as well).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Now I'm wondering, would I have the same/similar issues in case of using L2TP/IPsec instead of PP2P?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Pure IKEv2 might work fine through a NAT, but I seem to remember that Windows' IKEv1 client (the one that's used for "L2TP/IPsec") needs an annoying registry hack in order to enable UDP encapsulation for NAT support. And overall my experience was that literally _every possible thing_ about L2TP/IPsec is a pain in the ass.